# $params['proportion'] = $height/$width; cause a dividable by 0 error

Tags: php, html, wordpress

http://www.new.techmoney360.com/ is the website and wordpress is what it's made in.

As you can see going to the website the warning is right there below the navigation bar. It says the issue is on line 125 which is this

`$params['proportion'] = $height/$width;`

the whole block of code is

```
if (count($background_image) && is_array($background_image)){
        $width = $background_image[1];
        $height = $background_image[2];
        $params['proportion'] = $height/$width; //get height/width proportion
        $params['background_image'] = 'background-image: url('.$background_image[0].')';
    }
```

not sure why it's doing this.

Also, does anyone know what I would edit to slow down the speed of this slider?

Comment: well, obviously `$width` is zero. Done any basic debugging, like seeing what's in $background_image to begin with?

Comment: Seems self-explanatory enough: the value of `$background_image[1]` is `0`. What are you expecting the `$background_image` array to look like?

Comment: Totally makes sense, but I cannot figure out where on earth it's pulling this 0. 
This is a shortcode that came with the template. So I'm not sure what the design goal was with this.

Comment: @Robolisk can you var_dump `$backround_image` to see what it contains?  Where is it originally being created in the code?

Comment: I'll be honest, I've never done php. But I found out the script was pulling a file that wasn't an image hence 0. I solved it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$width` value is 0. `var_dump($width)` will reveal it. Therefore you are trying to make a division by 0, which is mathematically impossible.

Comment: understandable, but I cannot figure WHY it's pulling a 0.